# How To Redirect at same location where form was, after submitted?

Tags: jquery, forms

when i submit the form, page goes on top, and my form is at the middle of the page.i want to redirect back at the same position where the form is after submission.
how it will be? please help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: ...or get the scrollTop amount and send it via GET.

Comment: +1 i just used the scrollTop in jquery. it works for me. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if ($('#message').text() != "") {
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#message").offset().top }, 'slow');
        }
```

here is some code that i used and it done my work.
page scrolled down where i want to show the message " Form Successfully Submitted "

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `onclick="someFunction()"` for that submit button.
Then,in that function just shift the focus to a particular item in the required form.
eg. `document.forms[i].xxx.focus();`

Answer (score 0):

I think using an anchor is the best option.
    `<a name='contentForm'></a>`

I think using Javascript is overkill, because you can do this without.
Just use http://ww.domain.com/?foo=bar#contentForm

You can also append #contentForm in the form: 
    `<form action='/url.php?get=true#contentForm'>`